# Reading binary PLY file generates weird results

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, fread, file-format, ply-file-format

My task is to read vertex data from a binary little endian .ply file. Problem is that I cant find a way how to correctly extract data, starting after the end_header line.

PLY file:

```
ply
format binary_little_endian 1.0
element vertex 240753
property float x
property float y
property float z
property float nx
property float ny
property float nz
element face 477808
end_header
(after the end header there is a A0 byte indicating the new line then, ...)
AC76A0C04301644163416a42 ...
```

I cant properly identify even first float. If I convert first 4 bytes using IEE754 representation of float, the result is -3.5047936775001176e-12, however first four bytes (= the first x coordinate of first vertex) should be -5.01449 (according to meshlab conversion from binary to ascii ply file).

I'm using c++ fread, fseek, ...

I tried to endian swap every 4 bytes but the result is also bad.

I think that I'm extracting the bytes in a wrong manner.

Comment: What have you tried? Extracting the first four bytes of your data (0xC0A076AC) and convert to float you get -5.014486312866211.

Comment: Im sorry I was mistaken in converting using online flash tool, now the problem is how to actually convert it in c++, can you give me a hint how to convert unsigned int to IEEE float?

Comment: If you already have the bytes that represent your float in an unsigned int variable then you can make a union of an unsigned int and float, assign the unsigned int you have to the unsigned int in the union and then read the float in the union.

Answer (score 0):

As described by @tinman:

> If you already have the bytes that represent your float in an unsigned int variable then you can make a union of an unsigned int and float, assign the unsigned int you have to the unsigned int in the union and then read the float in the union.

Comment: ([Comment converted to a community wiki answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments).)